# Why did En Sabah Nu want Professor X's powers?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

It's my understanding that En Sab absorbs powers when he transfers to another person's body. It's also my understanding that when Prof. X was connected to Cerebro, En Sab was amazed at his extraordinary psychic powers and wanted them.

First question: did En Sab make a mistake, as the psychic powers he detected were only possible through the assistance of Cerebro? So in a sense, he wanted Cerebro, not the Professor's powers?

Also, what happened in the scene where Prof. X enters En Sab's mind? Initially he overloads En Sab with all the voices he hears, but then En Sab grows huge and throws the Professor around like a rag doll. It would appear En Sab has superior mental powers than the Professor, as he won the fight with ease (though strangely it didn't start off that way). Since En Sab has stronger mental powers, why does he want the Professors?

One last part. In the scene where En Sab forces Prof. X to send out the message, can Prof X. normally contact all mutants mentally, simultaneously? If yes, what's the point of Cerebro?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Apocalypse a telepath?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131684/is-apocalypse-a-telepath)

Answer (score 1):

In the [Empire spoiler podcast](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/x-men-apocalypse/x-men-apocalypse-spoiler-special-podcast-bryan-singer-simon-kinberg/) for XMen: Apocalypse, Simon Kinberg talks about this (the whole thing's worth a listen but this specific point is at about 9:50): En Sabah Nur does have mental abilities, but the one he lacks and wants Xavier's body for is the ability to *control* minds, not just read them. Cerebro doesn't enable this power, it only amplifies it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's right. Where has Prof X used Cerebrum to control minds? I only remember him using it to communicate or find people.

Comment: @Celeritas: just because the Professor *can*, doesn’t mean he *does*. He’d only control someone’s mind if there was a really pressing need to do so, e.g. to stop Magneto carrying out his dastardly plans. Which is why Magneto wears his helmet: it blocks psychic control. (See *X-Men: First Class* for details on that.)

Comment: Reading your answer again I understand better.  I may have misunderstood why Apocalypse wants Prof X. Didn't he say it was so he can "be everywhere at once and see everything"? But according to your podcast it was so he could do mind control, does he actually say that in the film?

Answer (score 1):

Just on this point:

> can Prof X. normally contact all mutants mentally, simultaneously? If yes, what's the point of Cerebro?

No, he normally can’t, and he says so during that scene. However, Apocalypse is able to increase the strength of mutants’ powers, which he does for the Professor to enable him to contact all mutants mentally on his own.